# Левое расположение вкладок QTabWidget в PyQt6

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt6, qtabwidget

Подскажите пожалуйста, как работать с `QTabWidget` в *PyQt6*?

Проблема возникла при попытке сделать расположение вкладок слева.

Пример кода, работающий в *PyQt5* без ошибок, а в *PyQt6* выдает ошибку:

> AttributeError: type object 'QTabWidget' has no attribute 'West'

---

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QTabWidget, QApplication, QWidget, QHBoxLayout


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        main = QWidget(self)
        main.resize(200, 200)
        box = QHBoxLayout()
        main.setLayout(box)

        tabWidgetObjects = QTabWidget(self)
        #tabWidgetObjects.setTabPosition(QTabWidget.West)
        tabObjects_1 = QWidget()
        tabObjects_1.setObjectName("tabObjects_1")
        tabObjects_2 = QWidget()
        tabObjects_2.setObjectName("tabObjects_2")

        tabWidgetObjects.addTab(tabObjects_1, "вкладка 1")
        tabWidgetObjects.addTab(tabObjects_2, "вкладка 2")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*PyQt6* для всех флагов перечисления требуется явное имя перечисления.

Измените на

```
tabWidgetObjects.setTabPosition(QTabWidget.TabPosition.West)
```

> tabPosition : [**TabPosition**](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-dev/qtabwidget.html#tabPosition-prop)
>
> Это свойство содержит положение вкладок в этом виджете вкладок. 
> Возможные значения этого свойства описываются перечислением `TabPosition`.
> По умолчанию для этого свойства установлено значение North.

Comment: Спасибо :-) голову сломал пока пытался самостоятельно понять в чем проблема.

Comment: @inesta пожалуйста.